# Facebook Graph API v2.2 get tagged places from friends tags status and photos

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get places where user has been tagged in a friend status , his status or a photos in an android application 
How can i do it?
thanks

Comment: i tried /tagged_places but it only return the user places from his status

Comment: were you able to figure out how to get friends tagged_places ?